# AJAX: Update textarea on page without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to update a textarea on my webpage when a form is submitted without refreshing the whole page. I've tried using AJAX like this:

```
$("#db_info").load(document.location.href + ' #db_info');
```

but when I submit the form, instead of just updating the text in the textarea, it creates a new nested text area inside of it, and causing it to appear blank. How can I update the textarea without reloading the page completely?

Edit:
I figured it out finally. What I used is:

```
$.get("", function(data){
    document.getElementById("db_info").innerHTML = $(data).find('#db_info').html();
});
```

Comment: This jQuery form plugin might help: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't really understand your question but if you want to change the value of a `textarea` you should do this:

```
$("textarea#textareaid").val(value);
```

Comment: AJAX has a `.load` function. It changes the value of something in the page from the id without refreshing the whole page. `$("#db_info").load` is going to change the value of the textarea with the id `db_info`. The second part: `(document.location.href + ' #db_info')` is what it will put inside the text area. It takes a webpage as an argument, but it can be narrowed down to a part of the webpage by ID. When I try to use it, it inserts a textarea inside the original one, making them nested, and have nothing appear in it.

Comment: This helped me a lot, because of unknown bug construction like $("#textareaid").val(value); was not refreshing (disregarding to text() or val()) use $("textarea#textareaid").val(value);